# Как правильно будет перевести на английский

Tags: html

Немножко будет не по теме программирования, но это его касается. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно будет перевести вот такое предложений на английский: "Веб сервис контроля родителями успеваемости и посещений школы ребенком"

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что явно не по теме.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Student school attendance and academic performance monitoring web service